# Create object of generic type T

Tags: java, generics

I'm passing a generic argument to my class, but I wonder how can I create an object of the type `T`?

```
public class Metadata<T> {
    private T t;
    private int type;
    public Metadata(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public void store() {
        this.t = new T(type); // compile error
    }
}
```

I can't just pass in an object of `T` because creating T require arguments that is passed to the generic class and it should be created inside the `Metadata` class not outside. How can I fix this?

Comment: The easy answer is to use a Provider. Have `Metadata` receive a parameter of type `Provider<T>`, then it can call `provider.get()` to create T instances.

Comment: @NoDataFound I know, right? Finding the right dupe target is a lot of work these days

Comment: By `Provider` is it a jdk interface? I only find `java.util.function.Supplier<T>`.

Comment: I think `Jorn` meant custom interface, which will **provide** you an instance

Comment: But you can use `java.util.function.Supplier<T>` indeed

Comment: What's in a name :) Yes, Supplier works

Comment: “…creating T require arguments that is passed to the generic class.”  I gather there are more arguments than just `int type` passed to each constructor, then?

Answer (score 1):

You can immediately pass the instance to the constructor like:

```
public Metadata(T t) {
        this.t = t;
}
```

or use  Supplier interface to instantiate an object of the generic type T:

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class Metadata<T> {
    private T t;

    public Metadata(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        this.t = supplier.get();
    }

    public T getT() {
        return t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int type = 1;

        Metadata<MyDto> metadata = new Metadata<>(() -> new MyDto(type));

        MyDto result = metadata.getT();

        System.out.println(result); // MyDto{type=1}
    }

    static class MyDto {
        private final int type;

        public MyDto(int type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MyDto{" +
                    "type=" + type +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no point in passing in a supplier, and then invoking the supplier in the constructor. You may as well have just passed in the instance.

Comment: @AndyTurner, yeah, it's true...

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to provide the class to the constructor, although providing an instance of `T` or a `Supplier` of `T` would be an option, too.

Try this:

```java
public class Metadata<T> 
{
  final private T t;

  public Metadata( final int type, final Class<T> metadataClass ) 
  {
    final var constructor = metadataClass.getConstructor( int.class );
    t = constructor.newInstance( type );
  }
}
```

**I omitted the complete Error handling!!!** You need to add some `try-catch` or `throws` statements …

This approach requires that the constructor of `<T>` is public, and the class `<T>` is in an exposed package of the required module – if you use modules at all.

The advantage of the `Supplier` approach is, that is works independent from this, if the supplier can create an instance of `<T>` at all.

---

But what does the `type` argument is doing? Is that type independent from the metadata class? Otherwise it would be obsolete; at least you can set it internally through the constructor of the metadata class. Or you can have just one class, using the `type` as discriminator.